# C# MVC: displaying list items with ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to display list items with AJAX.
First, when you go into the page, you will see the first item of the list.
After clicking "Next", then AJAX will refresh its div with the next item in the list.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
          return PartialView(_attractions.Last());
        }

        return View(_attractions.First());
    }
```

**View**

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
@model EasyTripNow.Models.Attraction

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

    @Html.Partial("_Attraction", Model)

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
        new AjaxOptions()
        {
            HttpMethod = "get",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "newAttraction"
        }))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Next"/>
    }
```

**Attraction Partial View**

```
@model EasyTripNow.Models.Attraction

<html>

<head>
    <title>Hi</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="newAttraction">
    <h4>Attraction</h4>
    @Html.EditorForModel(Model)
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = Model.ID}) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

**Controller**

```
   public ActionResult Index(int? index)
   {

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView(_attractionList.ElementAt(index.Value)); // next element in the list
        }

        return View(_attractionList.First());
    }
```

**View**

```
@model EasyTripNow.Models.Attraction

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<html>


<head>
    <title>Hi</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="attraction">
    @Html.Partial("_Attraction", Model)
    <button id="next" type="button">Next</button>
</div>

<script>
    var idx = 0;
    var container = $('#attraction');
    var url = '@Url.Action("Index")';
    $('#next').click(function() {
        idx++; // increment
        $.get(url, { index: idx }, function(response) {
            container.empty().append(response);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Attraction Partial view:**

```
@model EasyTripNow.Models.Attraction

<html>

<head>
    <title>Hi</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Attraction</h4>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ID)
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = Model.ID}) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Can't think of a good way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you have `Ajax.BeginForm()`? - its a looks like your doing a GET, not a post. Your index method needs a parameter to accept the index of the item you want and you would need to increment that value in each call

Comment: and who will increment that value?

Comment: Best would be to get rid of the obsolete `Ajax` helpers and just use jquery. Include a javascript variable initially set to zero and increment it each call. If your not clear, let me know and I'll post and answer

Comment: Not very familiar with javascript and jquery and that's why i'm using the helper.
Can you please post the answer? Thanks a lot!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `Index()` method needs to have a parameter identifying the index of the item to return in the partial view (renaming it to `Details()` might be more appropriate)

```
public ActionResult Index(int? index)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("_Attraction", _attractionList.ElementAt(index.Value));
    }
   return View(_attractionList.First());
}
```

and in the view

```
@model EasyTripNow.Models.Attraction
....
<div id="attraction">
    @Html.Partial("_Attraction", Model)
</div>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>

<script>
    var idx = 0;
    var container = $('#attraction');
    var url = '@Url.Action("Index")';
    $('#next').click(function() {
        idx++; // increment
        $.get(url, { index: idx }, function(response) {
          container.empty().append(response);
        });
    });
</script>
```